# How to find a List item by using its id

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to find a List item by using its id..i tried like below...But it is not works for me...

```
 $("#tabs li").find("#" + tabName+"1").addClass("current");
```

Please help me...

Comment: Have you ever tried it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
  <ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
  </ul>
```

We can select the list items and iterate across them:

```
$('li').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#" + tabName+"1").addClass("current");
```

? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').each(function() {
var checkID = $(this).attr("id");
//now if you find the id your are searching for
 if(checkID=="searchedID")
  {
    $(this).addClass('yourClass');
   }
});
```